# How does CouchDB handle UTF-8?

Tags: utf-8, couchdb

I'm quite puzzled by CouchDB: if I send a PUT request with some JSON string fields encoded as UTF-8, the non 7 bit ASCII characters get converted to the "\uXXXX" escape sequence. Is there any way to tell it not to escape UNICODE?

Answer (score 5):

Those `\uXXXX` are the correct way of encoding UTF-8 characters in Javascript.

Considering CouchDB is accessed using JSON *(i.e. Javascript data)*, those sequences should be interepreted when using the data, and this should not be a problem.

Comment: I am also facing issue in retrieving DBCS characters which stored to CouchDB bucket. Can any one help with this?

Answer (score 0):

CouchDB use mochiweb to handle JSON encoding/decoding.

There is an argument do encoding routine witch tells to output without those `\uXXXX`.

Simple way to apply patch is:

1. get CouchDB source
2. edit src/mochiweb/mochijson2.erl
3. Find `-record(encoder, {handler=null, utf8=false}).` around line 45.
4. Change to `utf8=true`
5. make clean; make; make install

I found the discussion with Chris Anderson http://erlangine.feautec.pp.ru/?p=232 and it tells me there is a chance to get this behavior out of box if someone care to make proper patch to CouchDB.